# How to set start time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I was trying to set start time using [xdsoft dateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). I just want to see 00:00 time when I open picker at first time, but I've got a current time. As [documentation](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker) says, all I have to do is set `startTime : "my time"`, but I have no effect. Also example of [startDate](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#startdateex) doesn't work.
My code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(
            "#<c:out value="${requestItem.fieldNumber}"/>")
            .datetimepicker(
                    {

                        lang : 'ru',
                        i18n : {
                            ru : {

                                months : [
                                        'Январь',
                                        'Февраль',
                                        'Март',
                                        'Апрель',
                                        'Май',
                                        'Июнь',
                                        'Июль',
                                        'Август',
                                        'Сентябрь',
                                        'Октябрь',
                                        'Ноябрь',
                                        'Декабрь', ],
                                dayOfWeek : [
                                        "Вс",
                                        "Пн",
                                        "Вт",
                                        "Ср",
                                        "Чт",
                                        "Пт",
                                        "Сб", ]
                            }
                        },
                        startDate:'1987/12/03',
                        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
                        timepicker : true,
                        format : 'd.m.Y H:i'
                    });

</script>
```

Comment: There was a useful comment. Dude pls go back.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i',
  defaultTime:'00:00'
});
```